# Navigating to another page , results in previous page rebuilding

Tags: dart, flutter

i have a http call to upload image to server , after navigating from this page to another page , results in another http call , thus uploading the same image multiple times and this process continues . I am navigating to another page using Navigator.push method , can anybody help me in figuring out the solution to this problem.I believe this is a known issue with flutter , while we should assume that rebuilding is as intended but it results in unnecessary http calls.

i have tried calling http request in initState , but did'nt worked.

i expect the image to be uploaded only once after navigating to next page , but the actual result is , multiple copies of that particular image is uploaded.

Comment: You could use a boolean on your state that's uploading the image. When the image upload is done, just set the boolean to false and check it before making the http call. Also some code would help, maybe the problem is in a different place.

Comment: What did not work out when using `initState` in a [StatefulWidget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) ? The `build` method is called each time the widgets are rebuild. The transition from a page to another requires both to be build multiple itmes.